# How do I fix a "Request format is unrecognized for URL..." error in a web service running in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am get the following error while running web service in IIS:

> Server Error in '/Inbox Sevice'
>   Application. Request format is
>   unrecognized for URL unexpectedly
>   ending in '/GetMailsInfo'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Request format is unrecognized for URL
>   unexpectedly ending in
>   '/GetMailsInfo'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Request
>   format is unrecognized for URL
>   unexpectedly ending in
>   '/GetMailsInfo'.]
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type
>   type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest
>   request, HttpResponse response)
>   +490982    System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext
>   context, String verb, String url,
>   String filePath) +104
>   System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext
>   context, String requestType, String
>   url, String pathTranslated) +127
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext
>   context, String requestType,
>   VirtualPath path, String
>   pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig)
>   +175    System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +120    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +155
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.42;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.42

Does anyone know why I am seeing this error and if there is any way to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657313/request-format-is-unrecognized-for-url-unexpectedly-ending-in)

Comment: To make it easier for Google, the German translation of the error message reads "**Unbekanntes Anforderungsformat für eine URL, die unerwartet mit '/_myMethodName' endet.**".

Answer (score 92):

Since HTTP GET and HTTP POST are [disabled by default](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;819267) try adding the following to your config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How come they are both disabled? What is enabled by default?

Comment: wouldn't using queryString have solved the problem? meaning ?op=GetMailsInfo

Comment: For asp.net1.1
 <webServices>
   <protocols>
    <add name="HttpSoap" />
    <add name="HttpPost" />
    <add name="HttpGet" />    
   </protocols>
  </webServices>

Comment: Elad Brenda, some of the older style asmx stuff uses query strings like blahblah.asmx/dosomestuff by default.  Another reason to upgrade to WCF I guess.

Comment: i can send request but not able to receive response from server , i am retiring xml from server . is there any more configuration needed .

Comment: Link is dead :(

Answer (score 5):

I've got the same issue.
To solve it add [ScriptService] to your service

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Script.Services;
    using System.Web.Services;

    namespace DemosAjaxcontroltoolkit
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Summary description for WebService
        /// </summary>
        [ScriptService] 
        [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
        [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
        // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
        // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
        public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
        {

            [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
            [WebMethod]

            public string[] GetWords(string prefixText, int count)
            {
                List<string> words = new List<string>();
                words.Add("Apple");
                words.Add("Appertizer");
                words.Add("Apple tree");
                words.Add("Apple Cider");
                words.Add("Afternoon");
                words.Add("Morning");
                words.Add("Breakfeast");
                words.Add("Lunch");
                words.Add("Spider");
                words.Add("Morning");
                words.Add("Day");
                words.Add("Travel");
                words.Add("Night");
                words.Add("Car");
                words.Add("Bikes");
                words.Add("Love");
                words.Add("Good");

                //return words.Where(w => w.StartsWith(prefixText)).Take(count).ToList();

                //List<string> returnedList = words.Where(w => w.StartsWith(prefixText)).Take(count).ToList();
                return words.Where(w => w.ToUpper().StartsWith(prefixText.ToUpper())).ToArray();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just out of interest (- in the case of accessing the web-service via AJAX); I've found that if a 'content-type' header is not passed (- even if it's a local/"HttpPostLocalhost" request), then the issue occurs, so I pass the header myself (- e.g. via jQuery's '$.ajax()' method rather than without via jQuery's '$.getJSON()' method), instead of resorting to this:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819267