# how to deal with this "unrecognized for URL..." problem?

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, json

[This is link](http://omaralzabir.com/request_format_is_unrecognized_for_url_unexpectedly_ending_in__somewebservicemethod/) which is explaining in detail, the problem i am facing right now.

I am getting a frequent exception whenever a call made to my web services. It returns appropriate results but still complaining about URL format.:-

> Request format is unrecognized for URL
>   unexpectedly ending in
>   /WebServiceMethod

So what do you suggest guys?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657313/request-format-is-unrecognized-for-url-unexpectedly-ending-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is quite a common issue that causes this error, that can easily be fixed by adding

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

...to web.config.  Hopefully that fixes it for you.