# Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/MyWebService'

Tags: web-services, asmx

I know that this is a question often asked in here, I have tried all the answers, and none of them work. When I consume the webservices I get no error message, and it works ok. But I do get this error 10-20 times each day. So someone do get this error, but I cant reproduce it.

Here is the error stack trace. Any help?

```
Exception stack trace: 
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

This is how I call the web service:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: 'MyWebService.asmx/MyWebService',
    data: '{"id":"' + id+ '"}',
    dataType: 'json',
    success:
        function(msg) {
            // Do something
        },
    error:
        function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Do something
        }
});
```

This is my very simple web service:

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string MyWebService(int id)
    {
       return "Something";
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I see in my logs that the user agent always is Google translate when this error appear.

`http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?hl=es&prev=/search?q=test&hl=es&client=safari&tbo=d&rurl=translate.google.es&sl=en&u=http://www.mydomain.com&usg=ALkJrhhcOM9LJgtG-RhFx1XSQw-g4h_tbQ`

You know how I can stop this?

Comment: Could you post the error message too, not just the stack trace?

Comment: The error message is in the title `Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/MyWebService'`.

Comment: Can you find the malicious requests in your iis log and associate them with your error? Perhaps something is messing with your URLs

Comment: I have updated my question with some new info.

Comment: @Martin Did you found a solution? I am having the same problem. When I am opening the URL from google translate in browser with FireBug enabled, I see some CORS and "operation is insecure" errors that are blocking my js scripts...

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the error only occurs when google translate requests your service could it be possible that google translate does not issue a POST request but a GET request to your service method? In case google translate uses a GET request your solution may [be here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657313/request-format-is-unrecognized-for-url-unexpectedly-ending-in) to stop the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already have both those in my web.config :(