# Calling asmx service from JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, web-services, .net-3.5, asmx

I have following asmx service

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

    public class DinnerService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        List<Dinner> dinners;
        public DinnerService()
        {
            dinners = new List<Dinner>();
        }

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public Dinner HelloWorld()
        {
            var dinner = new Dinner { DinnerID = 1, Host = "Ahsan", RSVP = "Some People", Venue = "Lahore" };
            return dinner;
        }
}
```

and I'm calling it from jQuery on page load event of webform as follows

```
    $(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'http://localhost:1901/DinnerService.asmx/HelloWorld',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data:{},
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#res').html(data.d.DinnerID);
                        alert(data.d.Host);
                    }
                });
});
```

It works fine on IE but in Firefox and Chrome it shows internal server error and response is like:

```
Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/HelloWorld'
```

This is very strange for me, why it's working on one browser and not on others. I am using Visual studio 2010 and .NET 3.5 for the service. Going to WCF for this particular case is not the option. Response on the internet could not help me solve the issue. What exactly is happening here?

Comment: Have you tried this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657313/request-format-is-unrecognized-for-url-unexpectedly-ending-in

Comment: there are lot of questions with similar title on the net but they do not experience the problem in one particular browser. Moreover, i can't find `<protocols>` section in web.config of the service project

Comment: If you don't have a <protocols> section in your web.config, just add one under the <webServices> section.

Comment: i did but to no avail :(

Answer (score 2):

The following setting to your web.config file will resolve the issue. 
See the [follownig](http://forums.asp.net/t/988377.aspx?Request%20format%20is%20unrecognized%20for%20URL%20unexpectedly%20ending%20in%20GetEmployees%20) post.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```