# {"d":null} append in ASMX Web Service respone

Tags: json, web-services, jsonresponse

I am calling a web service method which return boolean value in json. But on front end i am getting response **true{"d":null}**. {"d":null} is appending in response.

Following is my web service code

```
[WebMethod]
        public void CreateTeam(tblTeam team)
        {
            var result = BLL.Team.Add(team);
            Context.Response.Flush();
            Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
        }
```

Solutions which i tried:

- Add Context.Response.Flush();
- Use JsonConvert instead of JavaScriptSerializer

But both are not worked. How can i solve this? Please help?

Answer (score 0):

As explain in below thread remove content type from ajax calling

[ASP.NET AJAX returning JSON but not recognised as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939548/asp-net-ajax-returning-json-but-not-recognised-as-json)