# jquery ajax call works on localhost, but not on live server

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, jquery

I've researched this issue all day and it seems to be a somewhat common problem, but I have not been able to find a solution.

I am using jquery's `$.ajax()` function to make a service call that updates some values in the database.  It runs fine on localhost, but on the actual server I get a 500 Internal Server Error in the console window.

My client-side code is as below:

```
var param = FunctionToMakeKeyValueString();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../Helpers/Autocomplete.asmx/OrderStatements",
    data: { param: param },
    clientType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function () { ShowSuccess();},
    error: function () { ShowError(); }
});
```

And server-side code is:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class AutoComplete : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public AutoComplete () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void OrderStatements(string param)
    {
        IncomeStatementService service = new IncomeStatementService();

        string[] comps = param.Split(';');
        foreach (string s in comps)
        {
            int id;
            short order;
            string[] pieces = s.Split(':');
            if (int.TryParse(pieces[0], out id) && short.TryParse(pieces[1], out order))
            {
                IncomeStatement statement = service.FindBy(id);
                statement.Order = order;
                service.UpdateOrder(statement);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the actual asmx file is just

```
 <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/AutoComplete.cs" Class="AutoComplete" %>
```

I'm sure the url is correct (the .js file is in a sibling folder to Helpers, which contains the asmx), but is there something else that I need to set in IIS or the web.config file?  Thanks!

Comment: 500 is a server error. Look at the server logs - they should tell you what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment by @Mike W led me to look into the server error logs a bit, where I found:

```
Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
Exception message: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/OrderStatements'.
```

I googled that message which let me to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657313/request-format-is-unrecognized-for-url-unexpectedly-ending-in)
and it seems like it was as simple as adding this to the systen.web section of my config file:

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you Try adding below line into your web.config httpHandlers

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
     <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory, System.Web.Services" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I still get the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There Might be a problem with the Host link You have provided in JavaScript/Jquery

Please take a note down If you are looking this at chrome clear the browser data and you will see same result at both ends