# calling SOAP service with python client

Tags: c#, python, soap

Help me please to solve my problem with my python client. I want to get a reply from my SOAP service, written on C#. My service working correct when I try to test it in my browser, but when I started using my simple python client there were problems

```
from pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient

# create a simple consumer
client = SoapClient(
    location = "http://localhost:1906/AbitService.asmx/",
    action = "http://localhost:1906/AbitService.asmx/GetAbitReports",
    soap_ns='soap',
    trace = True,
    ns = False)

# call the remote method
response = client.GetAbitReports ()

# extract and convert the returned value
result = response.AddResult
print result
```

my pycharm told me, that

*Request format is not recognized because the URL unexpectedly ended on & quot; / & quot*

What did i do wrong? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I don't know if this qualifies as a duplicate, but did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657313/request-format-is-unrecognized-for-url-unexpectedly-ending-in ?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be that guy... but did you try doing `location = "http://localhost:1906/AbitService.asmx"`  That would appear to be the issue

Comment: Yes, I tried, still dosent work, but I have another error. Server can't recognize this URL