# Intermittent "Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in"

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, iis

Intermittently we see on a server the error

***Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in /methodname***

All solutions I have found for this error gives the same answer, which is what is answered in i.e. this question: [Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657313/request-format-is-unrecognized-for-url-unexpectedly-ending-in)

The big problem for me here is that my web.config file already includes the necessary info:

```
<system.web>
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet" />
      <add name="HttpPost" />
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
</system.web>
```

And it obviously works as the webservice can be called just fine, until it suddenly fails for no apparent reason.
Restarting the webservice (by forcing a web.config change) or even restarting the computer always brings the service back up, until it fails again a day or two later.

What can cause this error, appart from the HttpGet/HttpPost settings?

Comment: One thing we have seen (as this only occurs on a customers server) is that the customer seemingly abrubtly turns off the server every night. This usually doesn't affect the operation of our product, but in this case it might, but we're not absolutely sure, and we don't really see a mechanism that causes it to fail after a power failure.

Comment: Does the customer Shutdown, Power cord out, Sleep or Hibernate the server?

Comment: Have you tried the other suggestions in the QA you linked?

Comment: The ones that are relevant, yes.

Comment: Have you seen this [KB Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2803754) (Scroll down to "Windows Communication Foundation issues" and check the Issue 1's description.  Are there any EventLog entries after the service starts producing the error?

Comment: That KB is for ".NET Framework 4.5 in Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, and Windows Vista". The PC running the service in question uses Windows POSReady 2003 (basically Win XP) and .NET 2.0.
I guess the race condition can still occur on those, but as that KB and hotfix isn't for XP there's no help in it.

Comment: I know this one is for .Net 3.0, but might be worth looking into (Same KB type article, but for XP) [KB278377](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2783777)

Comment: I can see that that hotfix only includes one file: System.web.extensions.dll version 3.5.30729.7016. As we don't use .NET 3.x this wouldn't help for this case. I haven't been able to find anything similar for .NET 2.0

Comment: Just got definite information from the customer that this error occured again, this time without the power having been cut.

Comment: You will need to try and get as many logs as possible to try and isolate the issue. Ask for EventLog dumps, IIS logs, even Antivirus logs if he has one running on that machine. Anything that could indicate an issue with the web.config file

Comment: Event log contains nothing more than the same exception beeing shown in the "yellow screen of death" when accessing the webservice manually. IIS logs, as far as I know, only contains what page was accessed at what time, and what HTTP status code was returned.