# Handling malformed XML tag using SOAP Web Service in C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

I have created an ASMX Web Service to handle requests from a third party application. I used a WSDL that they gave us as specs for the request and response. I have matched those requirements and have my service up and running. I can test the application just fine using [Storm](http://storm.codeplex.com/). When we try to access the web service from the third party app, the request fails, so we setup [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to watch the requests.

What we saw from the packet captures is "[InvalidOperationException]: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in /MyMethodName". With a little research, I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657313/request-format-is-unrecognized-for-url-unexpectedly-ending-in). We tried that and started receiving a different error message. This was the error message/stack:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerType..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

I have tried most of the suggestions from the SO article, and decided to take a step back and remove the web service protocols all together from the web config. So, back to square one as it were. After further investigation, I noticed that the request being sent to our web service has what I would consider a malformed XML declaration.

```
<?requestXml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

Could this be the cause of my headaches? If so, how do I handle this? I obviously can't make changes to the third party application.

Comment: I would write a handler which just accepts the raw request, logs it and then applies a custom parser, which will allow you to deal with bad (but unfixable) requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did have to create a generic handler to handle this issue. The XML parser didn't care that the XL declaration tag was malformed.