# Access Denied for Web Service on Hosted server. Working on Localhost

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-hosting, shared-hosting

Guys i have a web service in my project which running fine on localhost:
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQHKh.png)

The same project i upload on myasp.net hosting. but webservice is not running their
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTMIY.png)

am getting this error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
```

Dont know whats wrong with that, Can some one help me...

---

***Update***:
I gave Read/Write permission to the Root folder of the web site and its showing webservice now.But its not pasing the json data after calling from the ajax script..

Comment: What do you see in the "Network" tab in the Developer Tools when you call ajax request? What kind of the request you call (post/get/put/delete)? As I know IIS can not handle put/delete requests out of the box

Answer (score 0):

As I can see on `get` reqesuts your web service returns me error `Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/getStudentLoginData'.`

One of the possible solutions is add to the `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer based on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/657315/1821692

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there's something wrong with the hosting configuration. You may need to contact your hosting provider technical support. The error is saying that it's not able to run the C# compiler. This is not something you would normally encounter with a correctly configured server.

Do other types of dynamic requests work, .aspx, .ashx etc?

Does static content work correctly?

Comment: Thanks for Reply.
Now its showing the web service but it not passing the data on the aspx page which is calling that service...
on localhost its passing the data properly...