# Running browserSync proxy (grunt) with Visual Studio code using IIS Express extension

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-code, iis-express, grunt-browser-sync

What I am trying to achieve is running browserSync with grunt while using Visual studio code editor with the IIS Express Extension installed.

I can ran both [IIS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=warren-buckley.iis-express) (Viusal Studio code extension) and browserSync using [proxy](https://browsersync.io/docs/options):

Gruntfile.js

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    sass: {

      dist: {
        options: {
          outputStyle: 'expanded',
          sourceMap: true,
          sourceMapEmbed: true
        },
        files: {
          'scss/global.css': 'scss/mccann-global.scss',
          'scss/_imports/theme/dark-theme.css': 'scss/_imports/theme/dark-theme.scss',
          'scss/_imports/theme/light-theme.css': 'scss/_imports/theme/light-theme.scss',
        }
      }
    },

    watch: {
      grunt: {
        options: {
          reload: true
        },
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },

      sass: {
        files: 'scss/**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass']
      }
    },
            browserSync: {
            dev: {
                bsFiles: {
                    src: [
                        'scss/*.css',
                        'index.aspx'
                    ]
                },
                options: 
                {
                    proxy: 'localhost:49798', //our IIS server
                    port: 3000, // our new port
                    open: true,
                    watchTask: true
                }
            }
        }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-grunticon');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');
  grunt.registerTask('build', ['sass']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['build','browserSync','watch']);
  
}
```

Grunt looks good:

[image]

Then:

Installed the google chrome [COORS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) plugin and the server run just fine trough the login page... but once I hit the homepage I got two errors: 401 Unauthorized.

[image][image]

I was looking into this:[Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657313/request-format-is-unrecognized-for-url-unexpectedly-ending-in) but didn't work for me.