# Why does call to web service (.asmx) fail when deployed to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

**Environment:**
.Net Framework 4.6.1
The .asmx file resides in my WebApplication project
Web Forms Project

**app.js in Scripts folder**

```
$.post("TaskServices.asmx/UpdateStatus", { 'id': 1, 'status': 1 });
```

**Web Service asmx file**

```
[WebMethod]
public string UpdateStatus(int id, int status)
{
    TaskManager taskManager = new TaskManager();
    taskManager.UpdateStatus((TaskStatuses)status, id);
    return string.Empty;
}
```

All this works locally on my dev machine, however when I deploy to Azure I get the following error message:

> Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in
>   '/UpdateStatus'.    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type
>   type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
>   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext
>   context, String verb, String url, String filePath)    at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext
>   context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: Some old answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657313/request-format-is-unrecognized-for-url-unexpectedly-ending-in) for checking, but not azure-related.

Comment: Yeah, this worked! The links explaining why are broken, though. Thank you! How do you put one of those duplicate indicators so I can mark it as duplicate? Or you can put it as answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: Click 'flag' under the post. If a *specific* answer helped, it might be better to post that as an answer. I'd be curious to know. Btw, did you get your previous Q answered? It was related to this (authorization error i think).

Comment: Re: previous question: I changed it from PageMethod to a web service (asmx file) and that worked.