# Asp.Net Ajax WebService and Internal Error 500

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, web-services

I can call the webservie directly to the browser with the following URL and it returns be all what I want :

```
http://localhost:64438/MySearchAutoComplete.asmx/GetCompletionList
```

When I add it to an autocompleteexetender into the Default.aspx page like that :

```
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" 
                  TargetControlID="TextBox1" 
                  runat="server" 
                  ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
                  ServicePath="http://localhost:64438/MySearchAutoComplete.asmx" 
                  CompletionSetCount="12"
                  MinimumPrefixLength="1" />
```

The page load, I have a textbox but I have an error 500 every time I add a keystroke in the textbox. I see the error in the FireFox FireBug.

```
http://localhost:62702/   --->This is the webpage that load fine
```

[image]
 --> This is the error

Any idea? I have noticed that I need to attach the process to debug the webservice, I might do something wrong with it too?

### Edit (Event Viewer)

If I go to the Event Viewer of my machine. I can see :

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetCompletionList'. 


    Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 8 
    Thread account name: MTL\daok 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at     System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I also have to start the webservice project first, than I stop it and start the webproject to be able to have both. The webservice still works (I can fire it directly http://localhost:64438/MySearchAutoComplete.asmx?op=GetCompletionList) but on the webpage I still have that Error 500.

### Edit 2 (Web.config)

Adding to the webservice project web.config:

```
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add   name="HttpGet"/>
      <add   name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
```

Have not solve the problem.

### Edit 3 (Direct call)

Calling in the Page_Load() the same method from the WebService work very well:

```
     string[] stuffs;
     stuffs = proxy.GetCompletionList("1", 10);
     MyList.DataSource = stuffs;
     MyList.DataBind();
```

But it's not working with the AutoCompleteExtender...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the event log on the webserver (i.e. your local machine) it should give a more detailed error message.

Add this to your web.config I think

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Comment: All is still in Visual Studio. It has not been deployed.

Comment: Alright this is what I see: InvalidOperationException 
   Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetCompletionList'. 
   http://localhost:64438/MySearchAutoComplete.asmx/GetCompletionList 
   /MySearchAutoComplete.asmx/GetCompletionList

Comment: I have the same problem. Could this be how the webservice is refered. For instance, I have to set the webservice as Startup project first, than I stop and Set the startup project as the web project. Doing this ensure that the webservice is running. In my memory, in the past, I had just to start the webservice and everything was up...

Comment: Did you try adding the <webServices> <protocols>
stuff to the web.config as per that thread?

Comment: The web.config of the WebService is pretty blank. The one from the Web Page has all "normal" tag that is required for Asp.Net Ajax stuff.

Comment: Then you need to add that stuff to tell it to allow HTTP post.

Comment: I added it after you told me :)

Comment: Same behavior, same logging message.

Comment: Exception message: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetCompletionList'.

Comment: That should have fixed it according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654099/how-do-i-fix-a-request-format-is-unrecognized-for-url-error-in-a-web-servic and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/0a47bb81-cb23-4cb0-bee5-2fa7813d05d6 as well!

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure you uncomment `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` just below the `WebServiceBinding` at the top of the web service class page.

That should get it solved. 
If it still persist, please check the URL of your `SitePath` making sure it is correctly rooted to the location of the webservice by including "~" before the URL as show below:

```
SitePath="~/Webservice.asmx"
```