# Ajax call to webservice fails

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

I have an ajax call to 
http://mydomain.com/ClientServices/RewardsService.asmx**/DisableDivAppsAreNotSupported**

which throws the following error:

```
<span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

<h2> <i>Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/DisableDivAppsAreNotSupported'.</i> </h2></span>

<font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

<b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

<br><br>

<b> Exception Details: </b>System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/DisableDivAppsAreNotSupported'.<br><br>

<b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

<table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
   <tr>
      <td>
          <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

      </td>
   </tr>
</table>

<br>
```

Why doesn't it recognize the op at the end of the url?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654099/how-do-i-fix-a-request-format-is-unrecognized-for-url-error-in-a-web-sevic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL is incorrect. Try:

```
http://mydomain.com/ClientServices/RewardsService.asmx/DisableDivAppsAreNotSupported
```

A couple additional things to check:

- Ensure that script services is enabled
  `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]`
- Ensure net's expecting JSON `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]`
- Ensure `get` and `post` are enabled:

> ```
> <configuration>
>     <system.web>
>     <webServices>
>         <protocols>
>             <add name="HttpGet"/>
>             <add name="HttpPost"/>
>         </protocols>
>     </webServices>
>     </system.web>
> </configuration>
> ```

Comment: My bad, the ajax calls "../DisableDivAppsAreNotSupported" and get this error.  script services is enabled. I want to return void, not Json. Any other idea?

Comment: Post your JS/jQuery and your service definition (at least the signature of the method). Also, see edit - have you checked your get and post protocols?