# Getting Data By Id with Ajax Jquery and asmx service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, asmx

I want to get selected Employee data by Id so a modal will pop up and show data for this Id. The Id parses as a parameter but asmx service won't fire at last.
Here is client side code :

```
 function getEmployeebyID(Id) {
        $("#ModalTitle").html("Update Employee");
        $("#MyModal").modal();
        var Id = Id;

        $.ajax({
            url: "EmployeeService.asmx/GetEmployeeById",
            type: "GET",              

            dataType: "json",
            data: { Id: Id },
            success: function (data) {


                $('#txtFirstName').val(data[0].FirstName);
                $('#txtLastName').val(data[0].LastName);
                $('#txtGender').val(data[0].Gender);
                $('#txtJobTitle').val(data[0].JobTitle);
                $('#txtSalary').val(data[0].Salary);
                $('#txtHireDate').val(data[0].HireDate);


            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                alert(errormessage.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Here is server side code :

```
[WebMethod]

    public void GetEmployeeById(int Id)  
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();

        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetEmployeeById", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
            parameter.ParameterName = "@Id";
            parameter.Value = Id;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                employee.Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);
                employee.FirstName = rdr["FirstName"].ToString();
                employee.LastName = rdr["LastName"].ToString();
                employee.Gender = rdr["Gender"].ToString();
                employee.JobTitle = rdr["JobTitle"].ToString();
                employee.Salary = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Salary"]);
                employee.HireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["HireDate"]);
            }
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(employee));
    }
```

Server side code is working when I invoke data when I am running it,so the problem is on client side and throws this: request format is unrecognized for url unexpectedly ending in /GetEmployeeById
As far as I inspected elements I saw this error : localhost:50791/Services/EmployeeService.asmx/GetEmployeeById?Id=42 500 (Internal Server Error). Can't figure out what's going on...

Comment: Try changing from a "Get" to a post. Also, asmx likes to return the data inside an object called "d"

Comment: where your webservice file is located?

Comment: can you access webservice using url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally from this [How do I fix a "Request format is unrecognized for URL..." error in a web service running in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654099/how-do-i-fix-a-request-format-is-unrecognized-for-url-error-in-a-web-servic)
 I added on web.config :

```
 <webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

And removed from

```
 $('#txtFirstName').val(data[0].FirstName);
```

the `[0]`
and all worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 function getEmployeebyID(Id) {
        $("#ModalTitle").html("Update Employee");
        $("#MyModal").modal();
    var Emp={
    Id = Id
    }
        $.ajax({
            url: "../EmployeeService.asmx/GetEmployeeById",
            type: "POST",              
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",     
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(Emp),
            success: function (data) {


                $('#txtFirstName').val(data[0].FirstName);
                $('#txtLastName').val(data[0].LastName);
                $('#txtGender').val(data[0].Gender);
                $('#txtJobTitle').val(data[0].JobTitle);
                $('#txtSalary').val(data[0].Salary);
                $('#txtHireDate').val(data[0].HireDate);


            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                alert(errormessage.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: this should work. Also add a [HttpPost] attribute in your asmx web method