# IIS: Getting error "error reading service" after updating my .net webservice on IIS

Tags: .net, iis

I updated my webservice with an extra webmethod, and redeployed my dll to the IIS server, and now when I try to access it from the web app, it gives me an error "error reading service".

I put back my old dll, and still it gives me the same error.

Any advice on what the issue might be?Would appreciate your help

Comment: We would like to help, but we need more info about the issue. Look in your NT event logs, under Applications and see if there are more details logged there.

Comment: When you say "redeployed", how are you deploying? VStudio? TFS build server? Drag-drop your ./Release/ folder?  Is it possible that your "redeploy" replaced more than just a dll?

Comment: Hi I just copy over the dll to the folder on the webserver. Sorry I didnt mention that.

Comment: @tgolisch, I was able to find my answer based on your suggestion. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The following error messaged displayed on my error log: 
**Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/'.**

This was solved by adding the following section in my web.config file

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
</system.web>
```

Reference to this question: [How do I fix a "Request format in URL error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654099/how-do-i-fix-a-request-format-is-unrecognized-for-url-error-in-a-web-servic?answertab=active#tab-top)